# WPF GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I am experiencing weird behaviour whilst using the WPF GridSplitter.

I have the appropriate HorizontalAlignment properties set to stretch and when I resize them the GridSplitter jumps around, sometimes going back to their original positions or just jumping around as I drag them.....

Does anyone else seen or know what may be causing this?

Thanks

Here is the XAML

```
<GridSplitter x:Name="grdTreeSplitter" Grid.Row ="1" 
     BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" 
     BorderThickness="1"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="0" 
     ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" ResizeDirection="Rows"
     SnapsToDevicePixels="False" ShowsPreview="False" UseLayoutRounding="False"
     DragIncrement="1"
     DragDelta="grdSideExplorerSplitter_DragDelta">
  <GridSplitter.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding 
      ......
    </MultiBinding>
  </GridSplitter.Visibility>
</GridSplitter>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem - dragging with a mouse - some splitters in my grid work fine, while others jump back to original position before I can move them. Sometimes dragging them a little bit and quickly releasing the mouse button helps unblock them, but not very often. All this while just clicking on a splitter and using the keyboard - works without any problems.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found the same code works fine in Silverlight while it is broken in WPF, so I think it might be a problem with WPF. My fix was to roll out my own version of the GridSplitter, which is too big to put here, so you can see it on [my blog.](http://xyzzer.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/fixing-wpf-gridsplitter/)

Comment: Wow, I put it in my application and now I've no more bug. Would deserve it the Microsoft Garagist badge if I could.

Comment: I'm happy it helped! :) Now what do you understand a "Microsoft Garagist badge" to be?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem it seems like we are drawing a lot of stuff. And if we have the ShowsPreview property set. The user can drag outside the grab-handle while it is trying to update the screen. But the user thread is supposed to be separate from the graphic rendering  thread so I don't know. If the user selects the splitter and uses the up and down arrows on the keyboard it works fine also. Ah whilst writing this. I tried using larger values for dragincrement and that seems to work also. Better solution. This is with two gridsplitters in the same direction(three sections of screen) I don't know if that is also your setup.

Answer (score 1):

My gridsplitter was jumping when I had width="1*" in grid columns.
I've set size in pixels and it stopped jumping.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but maybe this will help someone.  I was having the issue where the splitter would jump back to the original position after quick splitter moves.  The solution for me was to call `CancelDrag` in the splitter's `PreviewMouseUp` event handler.

**Caveat**

This may or may not help others, as I am working with a heavily modified derived class with additional functionality (including managing my own moves), and I have no idea if it will help (or work at all) in a simple scenario.